# HTML button not styling correctly

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to recreate buttons that I have already created for my desktop site by using the same css styling on the mobile buttons. i have tried deleting the css one line at time and it doesn't seem to be the css (after all the same css works for the desktop buttons.

The problem: I want the buttons to be completely styled but instead it is leaving the stock button and adding the style as a border

```css
#clients-title {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#clients-grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

#clients-btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

#clients-btn-grid .cr-btn {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#clients-btn-grid .cr-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  #clients-btn-grid {
    display: none;
  }
}

.mobile-grid {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .mobile-grid {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="clients-title">
    <div class="grid-items">
      <h2 class="m-heading text-center">
        <span id="client-r" class="text-primary">Client</span> Resources
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="clients-grid">
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        TD Ameritrade Access
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://www.advisorclient.com/login'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        American Equity
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://client.american-equity.com/Login/login?ReturnUrl=%2F'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        IRS-Where's My Refund?
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="clients-btn-grid">
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://www.advisorclient.com/login'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://client.american-equity.com/Login/login?ReturnUrl=%2F'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

If you click full screen after running the code you can see the buttons displaying correct.

SOLUTION: Instead of targeting the div that the button is in I just needed target the parent div with buttons e.g

```
#clients-grid button {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not style buttons inside #clients-grid. I also recommend you to use the same button tags for desktop and mobile view, because it would be a desaster if you have to change a link for example.

Just delete the .mobile-grid div around the button tags and style the buttons like in the desktop view.

Comment: Thanks I dont know if the solution I put in edit where it says "SOLUTION:" was what you were saying but that was exactly what solved it if so. As far as using different button tags I only did this because it was the only way (out of the dozens I tried) to get the buttons to stay perfectly inline. Without doing so it would make my buttons go out of line if the text above stacked due to browser size to compensate for the lack of space for the stacked text but the buttons remained on the not stacked text column.

Comment: to position your stuff, you could read about CSS grids or flexbox which are nice ways to exactly position stuff very easy along multiple screen sizes :)

Comment: Lol it is using css grid and was originally using flex, try running my code after deleting the entire "clients-btn-grid" and the css media tag @media(min-width: 800px). The problem is not that it doesn't display as an row (horizontal) the problem is that when the browser gets small enough for "IRS-Where's My Refund?" to want to stack instead of displaying the text on one line they are no longer perfectly inline horizontally. EX: I want the buttons displayed like; - - - but without doing what I have done, on certain s.size it goes; - - _ (dropping the button lower than the rest.

Comment: Oh I overlooked that you already use grid. But if the cells are well styled  the buttons should stay in one line.

Answer (score 0):

added

```
button {
    background-color: #4C9FCF;
    color: white;
    border: none;
}

button:focus{
outline:none}
```

```css
#clients-title {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

#clients-grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

#clients-btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  margin: 0 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 33.3% 33.3% 33.3%;
}

#clients-btn-grid .cr-btn {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#clients-btn-grid .cr-btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  #clients-btn-grid {
    display: none;
  }
}

.mobile-grid {
  background-color: #4C9FCF;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

button {
    background-color: #4C9FCF;
    color: white;
    border: navajowhite;
}

button:focus{
outline:none}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .mobile-grid {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="clients-title">
    <div class="grid-items">
      <h2 class="m-heading text-center">
        <span id="client-r" class="text-primary">Client</span> Resources
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id="clients-grid">
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        TD Ameritrade Access
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://www.advisorclient.com/login'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        American Equity
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://client.american-equity.com/Login/login?ReturnUrl=%2F'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <h2>
        IRS-Where's My Refund?
        <p></p>
        </h2>
        <div class="mobile-grid">
          <button onclick="location.href='https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp'">LOGIN</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="clients-btn-grid">
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://www.advisorclient.com/login'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://client.american-equity.com/Login/login?ReturnUrl=%2F'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-items">
        <button onclick="location.href='https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp'"class="cr-btn">LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```